# How to highlight markers and remove them in leaflet using jquery?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have this code below. What I'm trying to do is to get this button "$(#zoomTo"+str2.replace(/ /g, '')) to add a point or circle marker to indicated/Highlight some how to know that you are on that point on the map.

I figured out how to highlight the point with the circle, however, I can't get it to remove from the map when I click another button. It just keeps adding another marker circle.

Please help! Thanks!

```js
function refreshAttractions(){
$.ajax({url:'getdata.php',
 type: 'POST',
 success: function(response){
  if (lyrAttractions){
   mymap.removeLayer(lyrAttractions);
   $("#sidebar").html("");
   };
// goes through each point and creats a button id on the sidebar. 
  lyrAttractions=L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
   var str2 =  feature.properties.restaurant.replace(/'/g, '') 
   var str = "<button id = 'zoomTo"+str2.replace(/ /g, '');
   str += "'class='form-control btn-primary eats'>";
   str += feature.properties.restaurant + "</button>";
   $("#sidebar").append(str);

//creates popup info
   var str3 = feature.properties.restaurant+"<hr>";
   str3 += "Meal: " + feature.properties.meal+"<br>";
   str3 += "Price: " + feature.properties.price+"<br>";
   str3 += "Neighbourhood: " + feature.properties.neighbourhood+"<br>";
   str3 += "Submitted by: " + feature.properties.name+"<br>";
   str3 += "</a><br><button id='btnEdit' class='btn btn-primary center-block' onclick='editAttractions("+feature.properties.id2+")'>Edit</button>";
       
//used to zoom to area when you click on the button. 
   $("#zoomTo"+str2.replace(/ /g, '')).click(function(){
   mymap.setView([latlng.lat,latlng.lng],18);
   });
       
//trying to figure out how to remove the circle marker when clicked on another button
   $("#zoomTo"+str2.replace(/ /g, '')).click(function(){
   var high = L.circleMarker([latlng.lat,latlng.lng],{color: 'green',weight: 7,radius: 25 });
   high.addTo(mymap);
   //mymap.removeLayer(high);
   });
    
   return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(str3);
        }}); 
  lyrAttractions.addTo(mymap);
}});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the variable that contains the marker outside the scope of the click function and then use this to remove the old marker before you add a new one.

```
var high;

$("#zoomTo"+str2.replace(/ /g, '')).click(function(){
    if (mymap.hasLayer(high)) {
        mymap.removeLayer(high);
    }
    high = L.circleMarker([latlng.lat,latlng.lng],{color: 'green',weight: 7,radius: 25 });  
    high.addTo(mymap);

});
```